# How to use TensorFlow gradient descent optimizer to solve optimization problems

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I'm trying to use TensorFlow's Gradient Descent Optimizer to solve 2-dimension Rosenbrock function, but as I ran the program, the optimizer sometimes goes towards the infinity. Also sometime, without changing anything, it can find the right neighborhood but not pinpoint the optimal solution.

My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1_data = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_uniform([1], -10, 10),name='x1')
x2_data = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_uniform([1], -10, 10), name='x2')

# Loss function
y = tf.add(tf.pow(tf.sub(1.0, x1_data), 2.0), 
           tf.mul(100.0, tf.pow(tf.sub(x2_data,tf.pow(x1_data, 2.0)), 2.0)), 'y')

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0035)
train = opt.minimize(y)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

for step in xrange(200):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 10 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(x1_data), sess.run(x2_data), sess.run(y))
```

The Rosenbrock problem is defined as y = (1 - x1)^2 + 100 * (x2 - x1^2)^2, giving the optimal solution on x1 = x2 = 1

What I'm doing wrong with this? Or have I completely misunderstood how to use TensorFlow?

Comment: This code no longer works with tensorflow 2.4.1.

Answer (score 4):

If you decrease the variation of initial x1/x2 (e.g. use -3/3 instead of -10/10) and decrease the learning rate by a factor of 10, it shouldn't blow up as often. Decreasing learning rate when you see things diverging is often a good thing to try.

Also, the function you're optimizing is made for being difficult to find the global minimum, so no surprises there that it finds the valley but not the global optimum ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like @etarion says this is an optimization problem, your TensorFlow code is fine.

One way to make sure the gradients never explode is to clip them in the range `[-10., 10.]` for instance:

```py
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(y, [x1_data, x2_data])
clipped_grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -10., 10.), v) for g, v in grads_and_vars]

train = opt.apply_gradients(clipped_grads_and_vars)
```

Comment: Ah limiting the search space. I was thinking that too but didn't know how to do it. Thanks!